# Is it possible to run a c++ code and send the output to a python code in a bash file?

Tags: bash, python, c++

I have a C++ code that uses NVIDIA DRIVEWORKS (CUDA) and extracts some images.
I have a Python code that takes the extracted images and do processing.

My question is that is it possible to run two codes in a single bash file?

Any comment/help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: There are lots of ways to do that. But I don't think askubuntu is the right place. Try stackoverflow for programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of your question you want to run a C++ program to extract images and then put them in a folder. Then you want a python script to process those images. Based on that the script should be three lines to run the C++ code, a wait command to pause the script and then the call to the python script. You just have to make sure the python script is pointed to the folder that the C++ program is outputting to.

```
#!/bin/bash
./cpp_processing
wait
python ./python_script
```

N.B. Modifications to this script and the wait timer are almost certainly required.